# How do I tighten this toilet seat?

Tags: toilet

I have a toilet seat that is loose, but can not work out how to tighten it. I looked under the fitting but there is no nut. It looks like the end of the bolt is designed not to turn.

[image: Underside: looks like it is designed not to turn]
[image: Topside]

Answer (score 7):

All the work needs to be done on the top.

- See that metal disk on the left in the picture of the top-side. Press it in and its partner, and remove the seat/lid (by lifting off).
- Now remove the large (one inch-ish) covers that remain. Now you can see the top of the screw. Tighten screws.
- Put everything back.

To align the pins, turn seat upside down, and try to align. This worked good enough for me. I had no trouble with alignment.

Comment: "*Press in and its partner, and remove the seat/lid.*" **Remove by lifting or sliding?**  Just a guess but If indeed pressing the pin is   correct then i think there may be more to it. I would say   and lift up OR  press and hold them in while sliding the seat back towards the tank and it will then be able to be lifted up and away.